# How can i exclude my register page from Form Authentication Redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config

as the title says, i am trying to exclude a few pages such as my register.aspx from Form Authentication Redirection, here is my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyAppCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the location tag in your web.config.

```
<location path="register.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

See [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config) for more information.